# Recyclerview step indicator, steps are not full width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create some sort of a step indicator using a `RecyclerView`. Its width is set to `match_parent` and I'm using a `GridLayoutManager`. I always hide the left line from the first item and the right line from the last item. I also align the first item left and the last item right, while the other items are in center. I am supposed to get this:
[image]

But instead I get this:
[image]

Never-mind the size of the list, it will be different most likely each time.
Here's the layout for the `RecyclerView`

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>

    <com.musala.ui.uilibrary.views.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_text_view_default"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/stroke_separator_color"
        tools:text="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the part where `RecyclerView` is initialized:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), consentJourneyList.size());

    stepIndicatorRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.step_indicator_recycler_view);
    stepIndicatorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    stepIndicatorAdapter = new StepIndicatorAdapter(getContext(), consentJourneyList);
    stepIndicatorRecyclerView.setAdapter(stepIndicatorAdapter);
```

Comment: is max number of item in `RecyclerView` is fix?add your adapter and activity code

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers I've updated my question.

Comment: why are you not tying https://github.com/layerlre/StepIndicator? For same code, i thing you have to take three different layouts one for stating, second for ending  and third for intermediate position

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers I can't customize that library the way I'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

indicator_starting.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.musala.ui.uilibrary.views.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_text_view_default"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/stroke_separator_color"
        tools:text="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

indicator_ending.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>

    <com.musala.ui.uilibrary.views.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_text_view_default"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/stroke_separator_color"
        tools:text="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

indicator.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>

    <com.musala.ui.uilibrary.views.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_text_view_default"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/stroke_separator_color"
        tools:text="1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_list_divider_height"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/indicator_text_view"
        android:background="@color/stroke_separator_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter

```
public class AdapterMy extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterMy .ViewHolderEvent> {


    @Override
    public ViewHolderEvent onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view;
        if (viewType == 0)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indicator_starting, parent, false);
        else if (viewType == 1)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indicator_ending, parent, false);
        else
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.indicator, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderEvent(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderEvent holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    class ViewHolderEvent extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolderEvent(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (position == getItemCount() - 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
}
```

set Adapter

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 5);

    stepIndicatorRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.step_indicator_recycler_view);
    stepIndicatorRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    stepIndicatorAdapter = new StepIndicatorAdapter(getContext(), consentJourneyList);
    stepIndicatorRecyclerView.setAdapter(stepIndicatorAdapter);
```

Comment: Hmm looks okay but the first and the last item are not at start and end of parent.

Comment: you can align it to starting item to left and ending to right,but it increase the gap between two items.

Comment: your  supposed image also have gap at both side so don't add spacing for that

Comment: Even without adding the gap it's the same.